# Dynamic routes ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here is the component to render routes:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
function Profile() {
  const { nickname } = useParams();

  return <h1> {nickname} Profile Page</h1>;
}

export default Profile;
```

Here is routes

```
import Home from '../pages/Home';
import Following from '../pages/Following';
import Profile from '../pages/Profile';
import Upload from '../pages/Upload';
import Search from '../pages/Search';
import { HeaderOnly } from '../layouts';
////

const publicRoutes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: '/following',
    component: Following,
  },
  {
    path: '/@:nickname',
    component: Profile,
    layout: HeaderOnly,
  },
  {
    path: '/upload',
    component: Upload,
    layout: HeaderOnly,
  },
  {
    path: '/search',
    component: Search,
    layout: HeaderOnly,
  },
];

const privateRoutes = [];

export { privateRoutes, publicRoutes };
```

I want my Profile Component to be rendered when accessing /@mynickname. I am using dynamic router and when I try to access /@mynickname, it does not work, but if I access /@:nickname, it works.

How can I access /@mynickname and have my Profile Component rendered? Where did I go wrong?
localhost/@johndee -> johndee Profile Page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called url params, you can do it very easily.

Read about this here: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params

`@:something` won't work in my opinion, try `:name` and use the value.

Comment: :nickname works, but if I access :johndee, the Profile Component is still rendered. like localhost/johndee -> johndee profile page

Comment: or localhost/setting -> setting profile page

Comment: got it, so what you can do here
- declare /setting first then /:profile this way first the react will match with settings and then to /:profile as a fallback

Answer (score 0):

it's so easy

```
 {
    path: '/@:nickname',
    component: Profile,
    layout: HeaderOnly,
  },
```

To access it, just write `/@anythings`, if you write something like: `/anythings`, it won't work.

Comment: console: No routes matched location "/@anythings"

Comment: Try this `{path:"/@:nickname", element: <Profile/>}`

Comment: I change the path: to "/@:nickname" but it still doesn't work. /profile/:nickname works but /[something]:nickname doesn't work

Comment: Have you used `element` instead of  `component`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies with the version of react-router-dom. I'm using the latest version and the developer may have changed the syntax. When I use an older version, the problem is resolved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).